# How to find common columns between tables

Tags: sql

In order to join tables you need to have a common column. How would i go about finding what the common column is with one script? Is there a script that would search two tables I entered and return the common column?

Thank You
Mike

Comment: Sounds like you're assuming the common column would have the same name in both tables, which doesn't necessarily have to be true.

Answer (score -1):

Please find in the below the script for this query is an example:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM all_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = tbl1
intersect
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM all_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = tbl2;
```

Just substitute the actual table names for tbl1 and
tbl2 above. So this works for oracle.

Comment: The OP has not posted what their RDBMS is so you do not know if this is helpful. You are also assuming column names will be the same.

Comment: Hello and thank you.                                                                                              
      FROM all_TAB_COLUMNS is not being recognized "Error 1: could not prepare statement (1 no such table: all_TAB_COLUMNS)".   THoughts?